# Make gulp.js open non-default browser

Tags: node.js, gulp

The title pretty much says it all. I'm on Windows 10, and I have a node app that I start with `npm start`. (I know almost nothing about node.js.) The app runs on gulp.js. I need the app to open in Firefox, even though Chrome is my default browser. How can I do this? Here's the code that opens the app now; the docs don't allude to there being such an option for the `open` parameter:

`gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  gulp.src('./app')
    .pipe(webserver({
      livereload: true,
      open: true,
      defaultFile: 'index.html',
      port: serverPort
    }));
});`

Comment: This really depends on what `npm start` does ... what does it do?

Comment: As you are new, I'll take the liberty of suggesting looking at a build tool such as gulp. It has a module that can do this for you https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-open

Comment: @Aaron, great suggestion... this app is already running on gulp. Can you help with the syntax? Here's what's in there now; how do I add the browser?
`gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  gulp.src('./app')
    .pipe(webserver({
      livereload: true,
      open: true,
      port: serverPort
    }));
});`

Comment: Edit your question and I can give you an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Install gulp-open by typing the following in to your console

```
npm install gulp-open --save
```

Add the following to the top of your gulpfile.js

```
var open = require('gulp-open');
```

Add the following to the end of your gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('browser', function(){
  var options = {
    uri: 'localhost:<enter the port you are using here>',
    app: 'firefox'
  };
  gulp.src(__filename)
  .pipe(open(options));
});
```

Add 'browser' to your gulp default. This is what actually opens the browser at the port you are running your app on

```
gulp.task('default', ['webserver', 'browser']);
```

in console type `gulp`